# Ember / Ember Data - Error: The adapter operation was aborted after 201 created

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

```
Ember 3.0.0
Ember Data 3.0.2
Ruby on Rails 5.2.0
```

When using Ember and Ember Data to create a new record on a backend server using the default adapter (JSON_API) I get the following weird scenario:

The data is posted correctly to the backend and the backend replies with a `201 Created` reply along with the new record rendered as JSON_API. I have used `cUrl` to simulate a POST to the backend and the reply is correct. However the adapter still rejects the operation.

When storing the record I use:

```
newAccount.save().then(allIsOk).catch(failure);
```

Even though the record is saved correctly and the backend server replies with a `201 Created` the `allIsOk` is never called - only the `.catch(failure)` is triggered.

I have tried to change the reply from the backend server to `204 No content` but the problem persists.

The `CORS` config for the backend server is as follows:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'

    resource '*',
             headers: :any,
             methods: %i[get post put patch delete options head]
  end
end
```

We have developed a lot of apps in the past using the 2.x branch of Ember without any problems. I am really not sure where the error could be. The backend seems to be working correctly returning the correct data so I assume that the problem is with Ember / Ember Data or just me missing a tiny detail somewhere.

The only related topics I can find are these:

- [POST request to API from Ember often fails with 'The adapter operation was aborted Error'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44190636/post-request-to-api-from-ember-often-fails-with-the-adapter-operation-was-abort)
- https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors/issues/106

Comment: Cross posted here: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/5440

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to the problem. Please see here for info:

- https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/5440